# How to convert a column of characters of a dataframe into multiple binary columns?

Tags: r

How to convert a column of characters of a dataframe into multiple binary columns?

For instance, turn

```
> df
id name
1  A
2  B
```

into

```
> df
id A B
1  1 0
2  0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `table`.

```
> table(df)
   name
id  A B
  1 1 0
  2 0 1
```

To get *id* as column, strip off `"table"` class and `cbind`.

```
> cbind(df[1], unclass(table(df)))
  id A B
1  1 1 0
2  2 0 1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = 1:2, name = c("A", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Do you have better ways than cbind tables? I have many other columns so not just id. Is it possible to only have name involved?

Comment: @monotonic You might want to make a better example that conveys what you actually have and what you want.

Comment: @monotonic Not sure what exactly you want, but you can always do something like `cbind(df, unclass(table(df[c('id', 'name')])))`

Answer (score 1):

In addition, here are two other possibilities:

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>% 
  cbind(sapply(levels(factor(.$name)), `==`, .$name)*1) %>% 
  select(-name)


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Value,values_fill=F)*1
```

```
 id A B
1  1 1 0
2  2 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fastDummies` package was designed for this exact use case.

```
library(fastDummies)

df |>
    dummy_cols('name',
               remove_selected_columns = TRUE,
               omit_colname_prefix = TRUE)

  id A B
1  1 1 0
2  2 0 1
```

We can also use data preprocessing pipelines from the `tidymodels` metapackage:

```
library(recipes)

df |> 
    recipe() |> 
    step_dummy(name, one_hot = TRUE) |> 
    prep() |> 
    juice()

# A tibble: 2 × 3
     id name_A name_B
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      1      0
2     2      0      1
```

Comment: thanx for sharing `fastDummies`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`, set both `names_from` and `values_from` to `name` column, and `values_fn = length`.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = name,
                   values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

# # A tibble: 2 × 3
#      id     A     B
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1     1     0
# 2     2     0     1
```

Comment: we can also use `values_fn = \(x) 1` or `~1`

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
cases = unique(df$name)
df[cases] = lapply(cases, \(x) +(x==df$name))
df$name = NULL

  id A B
1  1 1 0
2  2 0 1
```